# Error 94 "invalid Use Of Null" in simple Access OK button w/multiple queries

Tags: ms-access-2010

Hi all and yes I have looked up the error but the cases are much more VBA-centric than my case.

I have a form I am using to offer the user a choice in member ID's using a search combo box to replace the usual parameter message box. It works just fine.

I have a report that takes the given input from the combo and through the query displays the correct data, works like a charm on it's own.

My report has two list boxes that use separate queries to display other information from the member pulling the ID from the same search combo and displaying it all at the same time, works just fine.

Now I have programmed a cancel and OK buttons for the search form (that on it's own before the button worked fine). The OK button shows this:

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
   DoCmd.OpenReport "rptGetMemberDetails", acViewNormal
   DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmMemberSearch"
End Sub
```

I tested it with a form and it seemed to work OK, but failed on the report. What I have found is if the member has no data for the two list boxes, the report opens fine. But those members with data for the list boxes throw the 
"invalid Use Of Null" error. So apparently there is a disconnect between the OK button and the two listbox queries.

Anyone have any thoughts as to how I can deal with this? I tried listing all three queries in the code:

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
   DoCmd.OpenReport "rptGetMemberDetails", "qryMemberTaskstatus", "qryMemberTestStatus", acViewNormal, acEdit
   DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmMemberSearch"
End Sub
```

...but got an Error 13 Type Mismatch error.

Cheers

Comment: No longer an issue - no answer, it just disappeared as I tried other ways of doing things. No idea what caused it or how I got rid of it.